# Keeping timer from Garbage collected in a console application

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection, console-application

All, I am monitoring my outlook inbox for some emails and parses that based on the content. I do this by running a console application and triggering a timer as shown below. The problem is this gets garbage collected after some time and I have to restart the app manually. I cannot run this inside a windows service as I get some permission issues while calling the Outlook api. Please see my code below

I tried doing a GC.SuppressFinalize(), GC.KeepAlive() on the timer object but no avail.

```
    class Program
    {
       private static System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            _timer.Interval = 10000;            
            _timer.Start();
            _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed1;

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


        private static void Timer_Elapsed1(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                _timer.Stop();                
                AddNumbers(2, 2);
                Console.WriteLine("The current time now is :{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                GC.SuppressFinalize(_timer);                
                _timer.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _timer.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Timer restarted from exception");
            }
            finally
            {
                _timer.Start();
            }

        }
private static void AddNumbers(int x, int y)
        {
            var sum = x + y;
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think the timer is being GCd?

Comment: I write the current time to the console every time the call back is triggered. After 2-3 minutes, it stops writing to the console the current time. This made me think that it is GCed

Comment: That's not how the GC works, it won't randomly clean out variables. There must be something else going on that stops your code running.

Comment: I don't have any other logic other than adding two numbers  in the code I posted above and I don't see any other exceptions thrown from the code

Comment: This code will run forever though. One problem, you only need the time start in the finally block, otherwise you are calling it multiple times.

Comment: Run it, wait until it stops printing to the console, and then hit the "Pause" button in Visual Studio. It will show you what code is currently locked up. I have a feeling you are getting into a race condition somewhere, the code above will work indefinitely, and I'm sure that it is not the actual code running on your machine.

Comment: @Ron Beyer, I was trying to reproduce the issue at work  on my home computer with this small code. The code I posted above stops writing to the console. Let me see I am running into a race condition as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Drop the SuppressFinalize. GC can never collect an object you have a reference to, and you call it whilst you have a reference via _timer. Why are you calling _timer.Start() so many times in your elapsed event? Just do it once in your finally. And why do you initially start the timer before you hookup the callback event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scope of your example application your `Timer` is not being garbage collected so you must be getting another error. Also, please see my note and example below about `GC.SuppressFinalize` because what you're implying and what it does are two different things.

**Loop instead of Timer**

Just a suggestion:  When using a `Timer` and the `Elapsed` event calls the timer to stop and then start again once complete this is a sign you need to have a simple loop running instead with a thread wait.

Since this is a console app and there are no other threads required I'll post a simple looping example that, IMO, would be more efficient and easier to manage.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int SleepTimeMS = 10000;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((state) =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(SleepTimeMS);
                    AddNumbers(2, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("The current time now is :{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                }
            }));

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void AddNumbers(int x, int y)
        {
            var sum = x + y;
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

**GC.SuppressFinalize Information**

Also, `GC.SuppressFinalize` does not have anything to do with garbage collection; it just tells the garbage collector, that when collected, not to run the finalizer on the object (the destructor method in C#). This is useful when there are items already disposed and you don't want to reproduce the work... For example if you're object is `IDisposable`, and you place the `Dispose` method in the destructor, and the user properly disposes of it when it is being used then you may want to skip the destructor.  Here's an example of using `GC.SuppressFinalize` properly.

```
public class SomethingDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Dispose of some unmanaged resources or something.
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); //We can safely skip the Destructor method (Finalizer)
    }

    ~SomethingDisposable() => Dispose(); //Just incase the object is garbage collected and never properly disposed.
}
```

**GC.SuppressFinalize Example**

And just for show here's a console app that illustrates the `GC.SuppressFinalize` in work.  I make 2 `IDisposable` objects. The first I actually dispose of properly with a `using` statement and the second I don't. Once they are out of scope they are up for garbage collection. I intentionally call the garbage collector and wait for all finalizers to be called so that we can immediately see results.

Notice the disposed object DOES NOT call the finalizer and the object that was not disposed does (which in turn calls dispose... which is the proper way to implement it.)

```
using System;

namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string DisposableTestId = "Disposable-Test";
        private const string FinalizingTestId = "Finalizing-Test";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestDisposing();
            Console.WriteLine();
            TestFinalizing();

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void TestDisposing()
        {
            using (var disposingTest = new TestSuppressFinalize(DisposableTestId))
                PrintTesting(disposingTest);
        }

        private static void TestFinalizing()
        {
            var finalizingTest = new TestSuppressFinalize(FinalizingTestId);
            PrintTesting(finalizingTest);
        }

        private static void PrintTesting(TestSuppressFinalize finalizingTest)
            => Console.WriteLine($"Testing {finalizingTest.TestId.ToString()}");
    }

    public class TestSuppressFinalize : IDisposable
    {
        public TestSuppressFinalize(string testId) => TestId = testId;
        public string TestId { get; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Disposed {TestId.ToString()}");
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
        }

        ~TestSuppressFinalize()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Finalized {TestId.ToString()}");
            Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Testing Disposable-Test
Disposed Disposable-Test

Testing Finalizing-Test
Finalized Finalizing-Test
Disposed Finalizing-Test
```

Comment: Every time i see `while (true)` my OCD kicks in and wants to change it

Comment: @TheGeneral Don't worry, it get's compiled to a simple cursive loop without testing condition and is the simplest way to do it. If you don't like it then don't get into firmware development lol. Also, this is based on the example provided in the question. This is more performant and less resource intensive, as well as being far easier to manage than working with timers.

Comment: There is a slight difference in that your solution will run indefinitely, whereas the OPs will terminate when they press a enter. It is unclear to me whether that difference is important to the OP.

Comment: @AdamG I'll give you that. I'll update it with a proper loop and read.